# How to mix lxml.objectify.ElementMaker with Sub/Data/Element

Tags: lxml

I can use EM like this:

```
myE = objectify.ElementMaker(namespace="http://www.vinoxml.org/XMLschema",
                             nsmap={None : "http://www.vinoxml.org/XMLschema"})

docO = myE.query(myE.querycreator())

docO.querycreator.name = objectify.DataElement(u"The Wine Cellar Book - version %s"
                                               % 15.1)
```

The content of the XML is generated dynamically, so I would like to be able to do it along these lines, but I get a 'no such child' on 'querycreator' when trying to add the 'name' DataElement.  What confuses me is the 'querycreator' is in 'docO' after I added it with 'SubElement'.

```
myE = objectify.ElementMaker(namespace="http://www.vinoxml.org/XMLschema",
                             nsmap={None : "http://www.vinoxml.org/XMLschema"})

docO = myE.query()

qc = objectify.SubElement(docO, 'querycreator')

docO.querycreator.name = objectify.DataElement(u"The Wine Cellar Book - version %s"
                                               % 15.1)

objectify.deannotate(docO)
etree.cleanup_namespaces(docO)
print(etree.tostring(docO, pretty_print=True,
                     encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the archive. My goal with all this is to move from Amara 2 to lxml.
I ended up doing this:

```
doc_header = """<query xmlns="http://www.vinoxml.org/XMLschema"></query>"""
nsVinoXML = u"{http://www.vinoxml.org/XMLschema}"

docO = objectify.fromstring(doc_header)

qc = objectify.SubElement(docO, nsVinoXML + u"querycreator")
qc.name = (u"The Wine Cellar Book - version %s"
           % 15.1)
qc.someint = 12
qc.somefloat = 21.2
qc.refcode = 1332322
qc.refcode.addattr('source', 'someone')
```

In other words, just needed to prefix things with 'nsVinoXML', i.e. the namespace.